# How to mock a Camel processor in a JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel, mockito

I have encountered a problem when I was tasked with creating JUnit test to one of my camel processor.

The main class is as follows: (redundant things omitted).

```
@Stateless
@Named
public class CalculateProportionalAmount implements Plugin{ // where Plugin is our interface extending a Processor
LocalDate now;

@Override
public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception{
    now = getNow();
    int startDay = getValueOfInputParameter("start") //just gets 1-31 from input parameters on exchange
    int value = getValueOfInputParameter("value") //gets value from input parameters
/*
More kind-of irrelevant lines of code. Idea is that the processor calculates number of days between "now" and startDay, calculates what proportion of month this amount of days is and applies this proportion to the value. 

So if today would be 1st and startDay is 10th (so 10 days between) when September has 30 days and value = 1000, the processor would calculate (10/30)*1000 
*/
}

public LocalDate getNow(){
    return LocalDate.now();
}
}
```

And for the test class:

```
public class CalculateProportionalAmountTest{
Plugin plugin; 

@Before
public void setUp(){
   //inicialize parameter maps, instantiate the plugin, so that we can reference it. "plugin" value is then instance of the "CalculateProportionalAmount" class.
}

    @Test
    public void pluginTestNextMonth() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(((CalculateProportionalAmount) plugin).getNow()).thenReturn(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 11)); //obviously does not work, because plugin is not mocked.... 

        ruleParameter.put("start", "10"); //here we set the "start" param that processor class gets.
        ruleParameter.put("value", "1000"); //here we set the "value" param that processor class gets.
        Exchange prepareInput = prepareExchange(scenarioParameters, ruleParameter);
        Exchange output = execute(prepareInput);

        String resultString = getScenarioParameterByKey(output, "result");
        TestCase.assertEquals(String.format("%.6f", Double.valueOf(1000) * 30 / 31), resultString); //obviously will not pass unless on 11th of December
    }
}
```

My biggest problem is that the `getNow()` method is and has to be called inside the `process` method, overwriting any attempts to specify a date.

Calculating the "real" proportions is also not viable option as we need to be able to check for variants "later this month", "earlier this month" and "today" on any day.

As the most feasible solution I now have is to rig (mock) the `getNow()` method to return a specific date when called from the test, but I need to leave the process method to be working as written, without any mocks.

The project this is part of already uses Mockito, but I am not very skilled in how it works and how to correctly mock the class so that it works as described above. I already made an attempt to do so in the beginning of the test class, but it currently ends in exception and I have been browsing tutorials since without much luck.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@Spy` i think.

```
@Spy
Plugin plugin;
```

And then in your test method you can manipulate with `doReturn` for this public method

```
Mockito.doReturn(LocalDate.of(2017, 12, 11)).when((CalculateProportionalAmount) plugin).getNow();
```

`@Spy` tag refer to real object and you can change the return methods of spy object.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito offers [partial mocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16) to mock methods like `getNow` and call the real implementation for other methods.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test camel route properly you should extend `CamelTestSupport` class from camel package. In general, they provide a support for testing camel.

My advice is to create custom route:

```
@Override
protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {

            from( "direct:testRoute" )
                    .process( new YourPluginClass() )
                    .end();
        }
    };
}
```

Then, you will be able to call it with `fluentTemplate` from `CamelTestSupport` class and test processor properly.

In order to mock behaviour of processor (partially) use spy from Mockito as @drowny said. Keep it mind that if you want to use `@Spy` annotation you have to init it with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` line in `@Before` set up method.

Comment: Hi! Can you edit the answer with a complete example of this? The full JUnit code.